# Delphi 2007 help integration

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

I moved to Delphi 2007 in early 2008.  It took a long time to migrate all my tools and components, and I'm not in a hurry to do that again.  I moved from Delphi 6.  (Bought D2006, but didn't use it much, due to the migration headaches).

The MSDN / F1 help "integration" though, continues to drive me nuts pretty regularly.  I access the D6 help files, and individual vendor help files as needed, but it sure isn't nearly as useful as the old put-your-cursor-on-a-method, click F1 -> You get something useful of the older help approach, especially with all vendor files integrated in.

It appears I may be very late to the party, but apparently I wasn't alone in this opinion:
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/deeelling/2007/08/21/38290

I see now that Embarcadero lets you download CHM files for Delphi 2007.  Is their any way to fully integrate them, and get rid of that useless MSDN monstrosity entirely?

Comment: I was not aware of the CHM files for D2007.  Now I don't have to open Delphi 5 every time I want help for D2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple:

Delphi 7 help for BDS expert
http://codecentral.embarcadero.com/Item/23948

Delphi 2007 Help Expert
http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24815

Answer (score 7):

This does not answer your question (I'm eagerly waiting for a good answer, myself), but [this tool](http://www.delphipraxis.net/731770-post.html#838434) does make the default help a little faster.  So you can get useless results in a reasonable time :)

Comment: I very much recommend this tool. I use it daily and it is just so much faster and less cluttered than the original help, it is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, sorry. I am just really curious how (and whether) you managed to resolve this. Having used Delphi 3/4/5/6/07/08/09 I must admit they done gone wrong with the MSDN "monstrosity" (as you call it) when they introduced it somewhere along the way. That was the one change I definitely did not enjoy.

Nowadays you're probably better off (legally) "obtaining" some PDF-books, as these can be searched through more easily than efficiently than Delphi help. Good luck with your new Delphi! :)